# Passing vars between deftests in Clojure unit tests

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write some unit tests, to test out some db models.

I would like my first deftest function to grab the db-generated ID of the inserted user, save it somewhere so that the next deftest can grab that same user from the db.

I thought I could do that by using `def` within the first deftest, but the defined var is considered an Unbound Var in the second deftest. Here's my code:

```
(deftest test-user->db
  (testing "Adding a new user record to db"
    (->> (user->db {:name "Bob"})  ;; returns a UUID ID
         (def mock-user-id))       ;; binding it here
    (is (uuid? mock-user-id))))    ;; this passes

(deftest test-db->user
  (testing "Getting a user record from db"
    (let [user (db->user mock-user-id)] ;; mock-user-id is unbound :-/
      (is (instance? User user))
      (is (contains? user :id))
      (is (contains? user :name))
      (is (= mock-user-id (:id user)))
      (is (= "Bob" (:name user))))))
```

I unfortunately can't find any resources on why that's the case. I can only assume that somehow the namespace's global vars are reset for each deftest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently tests don't necessarily run in order:

```
(deftest a-test
  (println "a")
  (def inner "hello"))

(deftest b-test
  (println "b")
  (println "inner" inner))

Testing tic-tac-toe.core-test
b
inner #object[clojure.lang.Var$Unbound 0x37acbc9e Unbound: #'tic-tac-toe.core-test/inner]
a

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
=> {:test 2, :pass 0, :fail 0, :error 0, :type :summary}
```

Note how "b" is printed first. That means your var may not have been initialized by the time it's needed.

I'd remedy this by declaring `mock-user-id` top-level, then using it in both tests so that test order doesn't matter. You can wrap it in a `delay` if you don't want it to be initialized until it's absolutely needed:

```
; delay will delay initialization until it's first used
(def mock-user-id (delay (user->db {:name "Bob"})))

(deftest test-user->db
  (testing "Adding a new user record to db"
    (is (uuid? @mock-user-id)))) ; @ to force the delay to run its body the first time

(deftest test-db->user
  (testing "Getting a user record from db"
    (let [user (db->user @mock-user-id)] ;; mock-user-id is unbound :-/
      (is (instance? User user))
      (is (contains? user :id))
      (is (contains? user :name))
      (is (= @mock-user-id (:id user)))
      (is (= "Bob" (:name user))))))
```

Comment: @cyehia Ya, np. Note that the `delay` may not be necessary. If `user->db` is expensive though, you may find it's nice to have calling it delayed until tests are run instead of when the file is run.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to @carcigenicate's answer above, in case anyone else stumbles on this topic and wants to run certain test functions in sequence (since, by default, they don't run in order).

In the particular tests' ns, create a function named `test-ns-hook` and invoke your test functions in the order you want them to run. If test-ns-hook is defined in the ns, the test runner will simply run that function, instead of all the defined tests in that ns.

So in my question, I added this function at the end of the file:

```
(defn test-ns-hook []
  (test-user->db)
  (test-db->user))
```

This ensures `test-user->db` runs and completes first, binds the variable, then `test-db->user` is run with that variable bound.